# sweetalert2 textarea newline confirm the modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, sweetalert2

When I try to break line in textarea input type, modal confirmed.

I had added these too, but nothing happen:
allowEnterKey: false,
focusConfirm: false,

any one had advise for my problem?

Check the code here:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/piman/f28tn8hq/24/
```

```js
$('.table button').on('click', function () {
 var replycontent = jQuery("#replyid-7 #reply-content").text();
 swal({
        title: 'my Title',
    type: 'question',
    input: 'textarea',
        inputValue: replycontent,
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Save',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
    allowEnterKey: false,
    focusConfirm: false,
    inputValidator: function (value) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (value) {
                resolve()
            } else {
                reject('Error!')
            }
        })
    }
      }
    ).catch(swal.noop)
});
```

```html
<link href="https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/assets/example.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <tr id="replyid-7">
                <td>

<p id="reply-content">Any Text here <br>
New line Test</p>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="author-info">by Admin</div>
                
                    <button>EDIT Content</button>
                </td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/706

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following control. But there is a bug, after pressing enter, cursor goes to end of the textarea.

```
$('body').on('keydown','textarea', function(e) {
    if(e.which === 13){
        e.preventDefault();
      var value = e.target.value;
            var start = e.target.selectionStart;
            var end = e.target.selectionEnd;

      if(start === end){
        value = value.substring(0, start) + "\n" + value.substring(start, value.length);
      }else{
        value = value.substring(0, start) + "\n" + value.substring(end, value.length);
      }
      //TODO - set curser position to (start + 1)
      e.target.value = value;
    }

    return e.which !== 13;
});
```

Here is jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/rosfc6r2/

Answer (score 1):

I had Updated to last version. It had fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix this by using the function below.

```
$('#id').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode === 13) { // enter key
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
})
```

On modern browsers you can also use 'e.which':

```
$('#id').on('keypress', function(e) {
    return e.which !== 13;
});
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: That didn't work this issue!
please check it in jsfiddle or code snippet...